# Compute $\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $1+\sqrt{2+(3+(4+\dots+(n)^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{1}{4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

$\lim_{n\to\infty}$ $1+\sqrt{2+(3+(4+\dots+(n)^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{1}{4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}}$

I am trying to use $e^{\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\sqrt{2+(3+(4+\dots+(n)^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{1}{4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}}}$=$\lim_{n\to\infty}e(e^\sqrt{2+(3+(4+\dots+(n)^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{1}{4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}})$to do this problem, but it doesn't make sense.

Also I try to use $\ln(\lim_{n\to\infty}1+\sqrt{2+(3+(4+\dots+(n)^{\frac{1}{n}})^{\frac{1}{4}})^{\frac{1}{3}}})$ it also make no sense...

so how to solve it?
And does it converge?

Comment: What is the problem? As in "does it converge?" or as in "does it have a closed form?"

Comment: does it converge? I'm sorry...

Answer (score 3):

It converges by Herschfeld's convergence theorem${}^{\color{blue}{[1]}}$

> Given $0 < r_i \le 1, i = 1,\ldots$ such that the series $S = \sum_{i=1}^\infty r_1\ldots r_i$ converges.
>   For any $a_1, a_2, \ldots \ge 0$, the necessary and sufficient condition for the sequence
>   $$u_n = (a_1 + (a_2 + \cdots + a_n^{r_n}))^{r_2})^{r_1}$$
>   to converge is
>   $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n^{r_1\ldots r_n} < +\infty$$

For the nested radical at hand, we have $a_n = n$ and $r_n = \frac{1}{n}$.
Since
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n^{r_1\ldots r_n} = \limsup_{n\to\infty} n^{1/n!} = 1$$
The corresponding sequence of nested radical $u_n$ converges.

**Notes/References**

- $\color{blue}{[1]}$ - Theorem III, Herschfeld, A. *On Infinite Radicals.* Amer. Math. Monthly 42, 419-429, 1935.

Comment: In my former comment I think it diverges.Now I read Herschfeld's paper and I am convinced that you're right...

Comment: Then does it have a closed form?Or what is it's limit?

Comment: @R.Sherlock Numerically, the sum converges very fast to around $2.911639216245824283883309537640...$. A search over math.SE indicates this number has been asked several times before but no one able to figure out a closed form for it.

Comment: @achillehui thanks!